# When does $p^s = 2^t + 1$ have a solution, for $t$ odd and $p$ prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, conjectures

If $p, s, t \in \mathbb{N}$, when does $$p^s = 2^t + 1$$ have a solution, for $t$ odd and $p$ prime?

Note that, when $s = 1$, we have $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, and therefore $t = 2^s$ for some $s \in \mathbb{N}$ (i.e., $p$ is a Fermat prime).

I do not know what happens when $s > 1$, or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catalan's conjecture is very far from being elementary, so I have sketched an alternative, elementary proof.

If $t>1$ then
$$2^t+1=3(2^{t-1}-2^{t-2}+2^{t-3}-\cdots+1)$$ 
so $p=3$. Now, write the equation this way:
$$3^s-1=2^t$$
or
$$3^{s-1}+3^{s-2}+\cdots+1=2^{t-1}$$
Since the LHS has $s$ odd terms and the RHS is even, then $s$ is even. Let $s=2m$ and now
$$(3^m+1)(3^m-1)=2^t$$
Therefore both $3^m+1$ and $3^m-1$ are powers of two, and they must be $2$ and $4$ (because no other pair of powers of two differ in two units). Thus, $m=1$, $s=2$ and $t=3$.

Comment: I'm not sure if the sentence "because no other pair of powers of two differ in two units" is grammaticaly correct. If you are a native English speaker, please fell free to fix it.

Comment: This is splendid, @ajotatxe!  +1 =)

Answer (score 2):

$3^2$ and $2^3$ are the only pairs of consecutive perfect power ([Catalan's conjecture / Mihăilescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture)).

Therefore, the only solution is $(p,s,t) = (3,2,3)$.

Comment: Thank you, @KennyLau!  I have overlooked that one.  However, note that my $p$ is not $3$.  Hence, does Mihăilescu's theorem still apply?

Comment: Note that, for example, when $s=1$, I have the known Fermat primes as examples for $p \neq 3$.

Comment: $p$ must be 3, take a mod 3

Comment: Okay, just so we are on the same page.  In this answer, is it implicitly assumed that $p^s$ and $2^t$ are *nontrivial perfect powers*?  (That is, $s > 1$ and $t > 1$ must hold?)

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris I believe you can handle the trivial cases yourself.

Comment: Now, I get it.  Thanks again!